# Rails server and cron jobs are crashes on server

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I use Ruby - 2.1.2 and rails- 4.

On server rails server crashes sometimes with no error in log files.

I need to restart server again.

Also cron jobs also getting crash.

In my application, I need to upload very big file (Almost 80 mb).

Please help not getting why server getting crash.

Comment: Very little information. What are you doing when the services crashes? Some activity before?

Comment: Not common activity..At any activity server crashes.

Comment: Maybe you could describe your server setting.